# Gesture recognizer on a circular view

Tags: ios, swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

In each cell of my collection view is a circular UIView. This has been achieved by creating a custom subclass of `UIView`, which I have called `CircleView`, and setting `layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.width/2` in the subclass' `awakeFromNib()`

I want to add a gesture recognizer to each CircleView. I have done this in the collection view's `cellForItemAtIndexPath`:

```
let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tap(_:)))
cell.circleView.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
```

The problem is that the gesture recognizer is called whenever a tap occurs anywhere within the bounds of the original square UIView. I want to only recognize taps that occur within the circle.

I have tried to solve this issue in the following ways:

In the CircleView's `awakeFromNib()` I set `self.clipsToBounds = true` (no effect)

Also in the CircleView's `awakeFromNib()` I set `layer.masksToBounds = true` (no effect)

Thank you in advance for your ideas and suggestions.

Comment: Have you fixed your issue with the suggested solution?

Comment: Adding a new instance of `UITapGestureRecognizer` in `cellForItemAtIndexPath` is not the best idea. This will add duplicate recognizers over and over when you're scrolling this collection view because the cells are reused.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can override this method in CircleView:

```
override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
    let center = CGPoint(x: bounds.size.width/2, y: bounds.size.height/2)
    return pow(center.x-point.x, 2) + pow(center.y - point.y, 2) <= pow(bounds.size.width/2, 2)
}
```

[image]

All touches not belonging to the circle will be ignored.

**More details:**

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622469-hittest
https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622533-point

The main point is that you don't need to call neither `hitTest` nor `pointInside` methods, you just override them in your custom view and system will call them whenever it needs to know if a touch should be handled by this view.

In your case you've got a `UITableViewCell` with a `CircleView` in it, right? You've added a gesture recognizer to `CircleView` and overriden `pointInside` method, so a touch will be handled by `CircleView` itself if a touch point is inside the circle, otherwise event will be passed further, handled by cell and therefore `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` will be called.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have added this function to CircleView, but am unsure how to use it. I have tried two ways. 1) Getting the location of the tap with `let tapLocation = gestureRecognizer.location(in: self.view)`. But now I don't know how to pass it into the function to check if it's within the circle. 2) I can instead use the collection view's `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`, here I can access the function with `cell.circleView.point`, but with this option I don't understand how to get the location of the tap to pass in.

Comment: By the way, the image is very helpful for understanding _how_ the code works. Thanks! I just don't know how to use it in connection with the gesture recognizer (or collection view's didSelectItemAtIndexPath.. either would work!)

Comment: @AustinWood You should not pass the location of the tap manually with this approach. If you override `pointInside` method, it will get called automatically when need. See the updated answer.

Comment: Ahh now I understand. Thank you. In the code you provided, I think it should be `let center = CGPoint(x: bounds.size.width / 2, y: bounds.size.height / 2)`. In your version the center coordinates aren't divided by 2. I changed it to this and now it works for me.

Comment: @AustinWood Yes, it was a mistake in the first version of my answer and I fixed it 10 minutes afterwards :) Glad that it was helpful.

Comment: Oh I must have copied it immediately and didn't notice the change in the code when I read your updated explanations. Thank you again!